# why selecting particular columns from same table slows down query performance significantly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, database-administration

I have `SELECT` statement that querying columns from `tblQuotes`. Why if I am selecting columns `a.ProducerCompositeCommission` and `a.CompanyCompositeCommission,` then query spinning forever.

Execution plans with and without those columns are IDENTICAL!

If I commented them out - then it brings result for 1 second.

```
SELECT 
    a.stateid risk_state1,
    --those columns slows down performance 
    a.ProducerCompositeCommission,
    a.CompanyCompositeCommission,
    GETDATE() runDate
FROM
    tblQuotes a 
INNER JOIN
    lstlines l ON a.LineGUID = l.LineGUID
INNER JOIN 
    tblSubmissionGroup  tsg ON tsg.SubmissionGroupGUID = a.SubmissionGroupGuid
INNER JOIN  
    tblUsers u ON u.UserGuid = tsg.UnderwriterUserGuid 
INNER JOIN  
    tblUsers u2 ON u2.UserGuid = a.UnderwriterUserGuid  
LEFT OUTER JOIN   
    tblFin_Invoices tfi ON tfi.QuoteID = a.QuoteID AND tfi.failed <> 1     
INNER JOIN 
    lstPolicyTypes lpt ON lpt.policytypeid = a.policytypeid
INNER JOIN 
    tblproducercontacts prodC ON prodC.producercontactguid = a.producercontactguid
INNER JOIN 
    tblProducerLocations pl ON pl.producerlocationguid = prodc.producerlocationguid
INNER JOIN 
    tblproducers prod ON prod.ProducerGUID = pl.ProducerGUID
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    Catalytic_tbl_Model_Analysis aia ON aia.ImsControl = a.controlno 
                                     AND aia.analysisid = (SELECT TOP 1 tma2.analysisid 
                                                           FROM Catalytic_tbl_Model_Analysis tma2 
                                                           WHERE tma2.imscontrol = a.controlno)
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    Catalytic_tbl_RDR_Analysis rdr ON rdr.ImsControl = a.controlno 
                                   AND rdr.analysisid = (SELECT TOP 1 tma2.analysisid 
                                                         FROM Catalytic_tbl_RDR_Analysis tma2 
                                                         WHERE tma2.imscontrol = a.controlno)
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    tblProducerContacts mnged ON mnged.producercontactguid = ProdC.ManagedBy
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    lstQuoteStatusReasons r1 ON r1.id = a.QuoteStatusReasonID
WHERE      
    l.LineName = 'EARTHQUAKE'  
    AND CAST(a.EffectiveDate AS DATE) >= CAST('2017-01-01' AS DATE) 
    AND CAST(a.EffectiveDate AS DATE) <=  CAST('2017-12-31' AS DATE)
ORDER BY
    a.effectiveDate
```

The execution plan can be found here:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJawDkTx-

I ran sp_help and this is what I see:

[image]

[image]

What exactly wrong with those columns?
I dont use them in a JOIN or anything. Why such bahaviour?

Table Size:

[image]

Indexes on table `tblQuotes`

[image]

Comment: Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) here are the instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

Comment: Execution plan is here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJawDkTx-

Comment: StateID has nonclustered index.

Comment: Those two columns are computed columns. Every time the row is read, the computation for those values is run and the value is returned. If they are slow, then I assume that the calculations of the values for these columns is slow. Since the `sp_help tblQuotes` doesn't return the formula, you will have to look at the table definition to see what is being done when you want to display these values.

Comment: The value just stored in table `tblQuotes.` for each `QuoteGUID`. There is no calculation when retrieving this column.

Comment: Please provide table size and indexes definitions

Comment: Table size and indexes provided. Thanks

Comment: Computed columns. Nuffff said. as @LaughingVergil mentioned.

Comment: But how can I see the calculation of those computed columns?

Comment: try this: **SELECT name,definition FROM sys.Computed_columns  where name in ('ProducerCompositeCommission','CompanyCompositeCommission')** .... what you also want to check is if the computed fields are "persisted" - if not then they are calculated every time you access that table.

Comment: You are correct. Those columns are computed columns and not persisted.
I am not allowed to make any changes on a table. Is any other workaround?

Comment: These computed columns use user defined functions, for instance GetCompositeCommission. UDFs can cause cursor like behaviour, RBAR (row by agonising row). This doesn't show up in query plans and only becomes obvious when you do a SQL Trace, through which you will see thousands of statements being run. If this is the case I would recommend finding another way of returning the results which doesn't involve using these functions. My only other non-related comment is that there seems an awful lot of indexes on tblQuotes.